# View form as live in Delphi Form Designer?

Tags: forms, delphi-xe2

I am using Delphi XE3. In the form designer, is it possible to view the form as if it was live? So that I can its really effect and adjust the controls, such as button positions.

Visual Basic has such a feature. So I just wonder if Delphi can also do in this way?

Comment: The Form Designer *IS* a live view. It is a real TForm window with real live components on it (components can adjust their design-time behavior in their code by looking for the `csDesigning` flag in their `ComponentState` property, handing design-time messages like `CM_DESIGNHITTEST`, etc). What more do you want exactly?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, not really real, as some invisible controls are visible, also there are grid points that should not appear in the real form.

Comment: @alancc: Not in recent Delphi versions, where you can not display non-visual components. The form designer is as live a view of the form as you can get.

Comment: If the form designer is really what you design is what you get, then why Visual Basic needs to provide a option to run form live?

Comment: @alancc you can [hide non-visual components](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Hide_Non-Visual_Components) in the Form Designer. You can also [turn off the grid points](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Form_Designer_Options), too.  Like Ken said, this is as close as you can get to a real live view within the RAD Studio IDE.

Comment: @alancc AFAIK, Visual Basic doesn't use a live Form window with live controls in its Designer, like Delphi does.

Comment: Maybe what you look is the not embedded form designer which makes the designer form a floating form. The IDE has an option for that in XE3 but this option is unfortunately removed from more recent version (10.4). In the not embedded form designer in XE3, your form is still embedded in another form contrary to what happened with really old Delphi. I really miss this feature and understand you. But it seems there was not enough developers wanting this feature and Embarcadero removed it recently :-( Nevertheless, with the embedded form designer, your form is still what will be shown at run time.